# iphone development

Tags: iphone, data-transfer

i am sapna.and we have to develop an application in an iphone having features:-

1. Identifies a unique user and captures profile.
2. Admin module / configuration module to assist user define the data points and their bound values.
3. Support of upto 250 data points to monitor, and monitor upto 50 on the client side
4. Provide tabbed interface with not more than 10 points of data grouped in a single tab / tag
5. Output to be generated in text and graphical form
6. Support iphone features of touch etc
7. Web service to retrieve point data from the database.

we have learnt that mac os and iphone sdk is required.now for data transfer what is reqiured ? is it API.or web services.what is reqiured.what topics ahoulkd be studied for developing this project.i am fully new to this domain.waiting for your reply.

Comment: I thought it was readable enough, NSD. Not everyone speaks English well.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP rest requests are very easy, and can be architected as non-blocking on the client side. The iPhone has minimal support for XML and JSON is far easier (IMHO) using one of the [json libraries such as those here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application).

You may want to use the deviceID as the unique user identifier (depends on your definition of unique I guess)

To learn iPhone programming, I can highly recommend the CS193P course available (at the moment) on iTunesU.

Answer (score 0):

For web transfers, you can do HTTP REST very easily so I would architect your server side to talk very simple HTTP. There is built-in support for XML, but you will have to parse results from the server manually.

For Tab UI support, you can just look at the examples included in the SDK, it's not difficult.

For graphical output, you will want to create your own UIViews that override the draw function. You will have to learn the CoreData API in order to produce high-quality renderings.

If you are new to this, and are more familiar with C# or even Java, I highly recommend looking at the MonoTouch system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all u need a Mac based system and the iPhone SDK installed. I think you are trying to make an iphone version of the web application. it will be better for you to download the MAMP(Macintosh Apache MySQL PHP) Server and install it to debug your application. its simply the mac version of WAMP and LAMP. (hope you are familiar with PHP).

You can then configure you MAMP for debugging and once the debug is complete you can host these PHP files to the actual server.

Remember, you need to get the results from the server in the XML format. and you need to write code to parse the XML you generated at the server.

Hope this information is helpful.